# Material design lite - css property: 'large-screen-only' renders then hides on mobiles

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

As my title states, I am having an issue with Material Design and a navigation menu which is to be displayed only on large screens, the full div is:

```
<div class="mdl-layout__header-row portfolio-navigation-row mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
```

On a small device the menu is displayed first then quickly hidden, I would like this to not render at all. Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? This is usually something that is handled with css media queries.

Comment: The mdl-layout--large-screen-only is the recommended way to hide items as per the documentation, I could add another media query but thought perhaps I was doing something wrong